# Passing the data of database in json object in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

Well, here is what I did:

```
     public function api_index()
{

    $agents=DB::table('users')
        ->select('id','username','role')
        ->get();

    return response()->json($agents);
}
```

And its throwing this in browser:

```
     [{"id":"1","username":"suzan","role":"Admin"},       {"id":"2","username":"momta","role":"admin"}]
```

but i actually needed is i need a json object and on that json object i need these data. may be like this:

```
    {"jsonboject":[{"id":"1","username":"suzan","role":"Admin"},{"id":"2","username":"momta","role":"admin"}]}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public function api_index()
{

    $agents=DB::table('users')
        ->select('id','username','role')
        ->get();

    return response(['jsonboject' => $agents]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
return response()->json(['jsonobject' => $agents]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following code :

```
     public function api_index()
{

    $agents=DB::table('users')
        ->select('id','username','role')
        ->get();

    return response()->json(array('jsonobject'=>$agents),200);
}
```